# Starting a service during startup

Tags: solaris, services

I've created a service for an application, and I want this application to be started on boot. In the service manifest, I realize that there's a property for this (enabled="true"), but I've been avoiding this for a particularly annoying aspect:

The import is part of a script. Having the service as "enabled" means that it will be restarted on import. The problem is that I'm not sure how to wait until the process is enabled before continuing. So, what I do in the script is import with enabled set as "false", then run "svcadm enable -s `<service>`".

So I was wondering if anyone had any answers for any one of these questions:

1. How do you make an existing service start on boot (hopefully avoiding manual additions to rc3.d)?
2. How do you make svccfg import wait until a service is completely enabled before continuing?
3. Is there an elegant way to wait until a service is started before continuing (avoiding manually grepping for enabled in a loop)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify question 2? I've created several services enabled by default and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions about Solaris SMF ...

1. To start a service at boot time, you simple must enabled the service with

   ```
   # svcadm enable FRMI
   ```

   For example, to enabled the service "ipfilter" you need to make

   ```
   # svcadm enable ipfilter
   ```

   This will be enable on the current milestone, so, there is no need to make any changes on `/etc/rcX.d` directory
2. I don't understand why you need the import process to wait to some other frmi, but, i usually import the "manifest" and after that put online with  `svcadm`, for example

   ```
   # svccfg validate MANIFEST
   # svcadm enable FRMI
   ```
3. To wait other frmi you can use the "dependency" option inside the manifest, as you can see here

   ```
   <dependency
       name='filesystem-local'
       grouping='require_all'
       restart_on='none'
       type='service'>
       <service_fmri value='svc:/system/filesystem/local:default' />
   </dependency>
   ```

I have many examples about how to install and use the Solaris SMF in my Blog (in Spanish) but, for example, here you can see a example,
[How to Install PostgreSQL 9.0.3 on OpenIndiana](http://sparcki.blogspot.com/2010/09/instalacion-de-postgresql-en.html) or [How to Install Apache Tomcat using RBAC and SMF on OpenIndiana](http://sparcki.blogspot.com/2011/03/tomcat-sobre-smf-y-rbac-en-openindiana.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps can you solve this by making your service dependent of another service not yet enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm not really comfortable with this particular workaround. I really appreciate the answer though.